# Error accessing SVN repositiry: URI doesnot contain the name of the repository

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to add SVN repository to my eclipse and I am getting the error as shown in the attached screenshot.

[image: svn: E190001 The URI does not contain the name of a repository]

I checked for the error and tried to reinstall and try everything I know, but of little use. But, I am able to access the SVN location using tortoise SVN tool.

Below are the configuration details of my tools:
Eclipse : Kepler 
SVN - 1.8
SVN Connector - 1.8.3

Please help me in configuring.

Comment: Can some one tell me whats the error : svn: The URI does not contain the name of a repository.

Comment: How does URL to repository looks like? If it looks like this: `server.com/svn`, try to add the name of the repository `server.com/svn/repo1`

Comment: @IvanJovovic  The URL is something like `http://ip-address/svn` . Under this `svn/` all the projects exists. So do you think all the projects have to be placed one more level down svn ??  something like `http://ip-address/svn/repo1` and `repo1` contains all the projects?

Comment: No need to move anything in SVN. When you access `http://ip-address/svn/` through `TortoiseSVN`, do you see a list of all repositories? If so, `http://ip-address/svn/` is address of your `SVN server`, not some particular repository. When adding path to repository to Eclipse, you will have to do it for each repository itself. Just try to add `server.com/svn/repo1` or `server.com/svn/repo1/trunk` in Eclipse.

Comment: No.. under `http:ip-adddress/svn/` I just see list of projects rather than any repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason was as mentioned by the svn plugin: There was no SVN location mentioned in the URL, i.e. the URL represented didn't represent any repository in the SVN. The format of the URI for accessing SVN repository must be http://server-address/svn/repository. I agree with the Ivan's above answer.